# Weird jQuery errors on character counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple character counter which shows whether the user has typed in the minimum number of characters before they can press enter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#notification').hide();
 $('#press_enter_notification').hide();  

   var allow_enter = false;
   var min = 4;
   var max = 30;
   var char_count = 0;

   $("#form_textbox").keydown(function() {

      $('#press_enter_notification').hide();  

      if(this.value.length < min) {
         char_count = min - (this.value.length) -1;
         //alert('Too short');
         $('#notification').show("fast");
         $('#notification').text(char_count + ' more characters to go');
         allow_enter = false;

      } else if(this.value.length >= max) {
         char_count = (this.value.length) - max;
         this.value = this.value.substring(0,max);
         $('#notification').show("fast");
         $('#notification').text(' no more characters remaining');

      } else {
         char_count = max - (this.value.length) -1;
         $('#notification').show("fast");
         $('#notification').text(char_count + ' characters remaining');
         $('#press_enter_notification').show("fast");
         allow_enter = true;
      }   
   });

   $("form").submit( function () {
      if (allow_enter == false)
      {
         $('#press_enter_notification').show("fast").text('you cannot press enter yet');
         return allow_enter;
      }  
   } );


});
```

It works, however it has the following quirks:

1. When you type something in and delete all the text, the character count message doesnt dissapear, or count backwards
2. When you delete everything it says 3 more characters to go, I had to add -1 at `if(this.value.length < min) {
            char_count = min - (this.value.length) -1;`, otherwise it lets you enter 5 characters before it stops saying 3,2,1 more characters to go.

If you try this out in a browser or jsbin you will notice them. How can I structure this to sort it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `keydown()` to `keyup()` as the length isn't registered until the key press is fully complete. The only thing you need to check for keydown with is if you're preventing the default on things like return or tab.

You can also remove the -1 hack now.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPD3j/

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues is that `keydown` fires before the action of that keypress is run.  You can fix this by changing to `keyup`.  There are many issues though with character counters on keypress (regardless of keydown, keyup etc.).  For instance, what if a person holds a button down, the even fires once.

I would consider looking at one of the many plugins already created.  http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/character-counter

EDIT: Slight modification, you probably want to bind keyup, keydown and keypress.  This will work around a few of the issues:

```
$("#form_textbox").bind("keydown keyup keypress"...
```

Comment: The event may only fire once but since he'll be checking against the eventual length on keyup it doesn't break anything in this particular instance.

Comment: Only one of many issues with key events.  What happens when someone pastes a bunch of text in?

Comment: His allow_enter variable defaults to false so the form wouldn't submit. I'm not suggesting what you're saying is wrong (that there are many things to consider with keypress) but I resent the implication that a plugin is necessary when the problems are fairly easy to overcome. Probably easier than shoe-horning in an external plugin.

Comment: A plugin is never required, it can just make things a bit easier.  There are many quirks to key events in various browsers, and it may just be easier to let someone else consider all of them.  Or if the possibility of the exact count occasionally being incorrect is acceptable, then just add a character count check on submit and be done with it.